# Programmatically import a module and also use `as` to give it a name

Tags: python, import, ipython

Is there an import utility, such as `importlib`, that allows programmatically importing a module *with a qualified name*, such as `import numpy as np`?

It seems that the plain `importlib.import_module()` and the `imp.load_module` functions do not offer this. [And the Python docs page on import tools didn't reveal anything either.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/modules.html)

Specifically, instead of just doing `importlib.import_module("numpy")` I'm looking for something that "just works" along the lines of `importlib.import_module("numpy", as="np")` making the name `"np"` now available as the imported module.

**My use case:**

I'm using the `DirectView.sync_imports` function from IPython.parallel to ensure that all compute engines have the needed modules imported on them locally. This way, a user can execute code in a controller IPython session, but the backend can execute it in parallel.

In this use case, since the code is often just interactive, exploratory scripting, it is important to match exactly whatever import statements and names are provided by the programmer.

So if the following is a function that the programmer would like to map to other engines and execute in parallel on a variety of arguments, the same qualified import would need to be available on all engines:

```
def my_func(x):
    import numpy as np
    return np.random.randint(x, size=(10,1))
```

To get 4 such results, in parallel, a user could do the following (assuming everything with `ipcluster` or `ipcontroller` / `ipengines` is configured and running):

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
rc = Client()
direct_view = rc[:]

# In parallel.
four_random_arrays = direct_view.map(my_func, [2, 3, 4, 5]).get()
```

IPython provides a nice context manager for syncing the imports:

```
# This works fine and syncs the import on all engines.
with direct_view.sync_imports():
    import numpy as np
```

But suppose you only have access to a string: `"numpy as np"` and you want to use `importlib` to do this within that context manager block **without** trying to parse the strings manually and tinker with whatever entries are in the loaded modules `dict`.

It's probably needless to say, but using `exec` here is also completely untenable, because what if instead of a module string, someone accidentally passes in something nasty or insecure, like a shell call to `rm -rf /`. Leveraging import tools that don't allow for execution of arbitrary code is important -- making it untenable to roll one's own string-parsing `exec` sort of solution.

Comment: Have a look at `imp.load_module()` and `imp.load_source()`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html The first parameter to these might be what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But from the main Python docs page on import tools, none of the existing ones seemed to have this basic feature. From what I can tell, the first argument to `imp.load_module` has to be the actual name of the module. Whereas I am looking for a function that will load a module, by name, but target it into a different name, that would normally have come after the `as` keyword. Ideally, I'd also like to be able to programatically deal with `from blah.foo import baz as foo_baz` statements programatically too.

Comment: I think it is worth trying out with `imp`. I have used it in one of my code and I just changed the name parameter to a random string and the module loaded fine. So it does not have to be the name of the module looks like. Although I agree I did not use it with this random string.

Comment: Can you give an example? Are you able to import a standard module, say `itertools` as a special name? Like `import itertools as itools` and then manipulate the module with `itools`. If you can post that example it might help.

Answer (score 3):

`import_module` returns a value (the module being imported) -- set whatever variable you want to the return value of that. For example:

```
import importlib
p = importlib.import_module('os.path')
p.join('/', 'blah')
```

would effectively be equivalent to

```
import os.path as p
p.join('/', 'blah')
```

Comment: This is helpful, but it's still not clear how to go from a string, or a tuple, or some other representation, to this. If I am given `v = ("itertools", "itools")` then I'd have to try something like `locals()[v[1]] = importlib.load_module(v[0])` or something... I can reasonably assume I would be passed a `tuple` like that, but that I don't want to manually modify the namespace -- I want that to be the responsibility of whatever import tool module is used.

Comment: @EMS: That's how you'd do it, yes.

Comment: But it's considered unreliable to count on modifying `locals()` -- so that's effectively not an actual solution.

Comment: It's also unclear from this how to handle sub-package imports, like `import scipy.stats` and have this accessible via just `scipy.stats`.